# Errors javascript in layout laravel

Tags: laravel

In layout `master.blade.php` I have a couple of javascript libraries

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script> //Mix
<script src="{{asset('source/admin/assets/js/admin.js')}}"></script> //Mix
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'notification' );
</script>
```

But in some layouts it extends from the `master.blade` page without using the functionality of that library, it appears error,

Example
In layout `ckeditor.blade.php` use ckeditor function 
so no error occurred.But when i go `home.blade.php` don't use ckeditor function so have error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined`. 
What should I do to get it to page understand what page need library in laravel mix, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you don't have Ckeditor element on that page. You should move this code to the `ckeditor.blade.php` view:

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'notification' );
</script>
```

But a better way to handle this is to use [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#stacks):

In the master view create a new stack:

```
@stack('scripts')
```

Then push the code from the `ckeditor.blade.php` view:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'notification' );
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: When i cut to page use ckeditor i have errror Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined @@